# Bootstrap Modal Backdrop only shows with "class=fade", not class="show"

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I needed my modal window to show upon launching of my page, and I was able to find that solution elsewhere on this site (changing **class="modal fade"** to **class="modal show"**).

However, upon doing that, the faded backdrop has disappeared. I've tried using the class "modal-backdrop" on the same div as "modal", but with the opacity set to .5, that makes both the backdrop AND the modal window transparent, which of course is undesirable. I'm not much with Javascript, so the problem could lie there.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
   <div class="modal show"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div>
                        <p style="font-size:17px;font-family: 'AntennaLight',  Arial, sans-serif;">Welcome to the <span style="font-family:'AntennaMedium',  Arial, sans-serif;">Lorem Ipsum</span> website.<br /> <br />
                        Please provide the ZIP code where you intend to register the vehicle and the intended date* you plan to purchase the vehicle.<br /> <br />
                        Thank you!<br /> <br />
                        </p>
                    </div>


                        <form id="msform" action='/Home/Submit' method="post">

                            <!-- fieldsets -->
                            <fieldset class="firstSet">

                                <p>
                                    <input type="text" name="zip" value="" placeholder="ZIP Code" />
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <input type="text" name="date" value="" placeholder="XX/XX/XXXX" />
                                </p>

                                <input name="submit" type="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>

                  <div style="margin-top:30px;">

                    <p style="font-size:11px;font-family: 'AntennaLight',  Arial, sans-serif;">*If the sale date has already occurred, please use that date.</p>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
  <script>
   $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.modal')
    .prop('class', 'modal') // revert to default
    .addClass( $(this).data('direction') );
  };
 </script>
```

On other sites I've worked on, using class="modal fade" works great, when there's a button to fire the modal window... but in this case I need the window and backdrop to appear upon page launch, and simply changing it to class="modal show" only shows the window on launch, but no backdrop.

Thanks!

Comment: so you want something which change your class="modal fade" to modal show... when window load?

Comment: I have the modal appearing when the window loads... but the backdrop (modal-backdrop class) doesn't appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give the model an id and start it modal like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#my-modal').modal('show')
})
```

This will keep the behavior that occurs when you trigger it manually using a button.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... so that would replace the script that I have now?

Comment: Yes... sort of: here is the working sample: https://jsfiddle.net/4h8L9ph4/

Comment: The code will cause the modal to fade in when the page is ready. You just need to add the id="my-modal" to the div like : <div id="my-modal" class=" modal fade"

Comment: @SergiuM this code work on jsfiddle, bootply, but not on local host .. same code same use.. but throw error $(...).modal is not a function

Comment: What version of bootstrap do you use? Maybe that's the cause so I'll have to see how is done in your version. The one I have tested on is 3.

Comment: Thanks for your  jsfiddle, Sergiu... I'm having the same problem as Mostafa, it doesn't seem to be working on my local host nor on my server. I'm using Boostrap 3.3.2. Perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: @SergiuM i'm using 3.3.7 those are used in your fiddle.

Comment: Looks like is working also with 3.3.2 https://jsfiddle.net/qrmLvegb/. What jquery do you use? There was somewhere mentioned that the bootstrap.js must be added after jquery but I am not sure if that is relevant.

Comment: It seems that it does fail if the order is reversed. So you will need to add jquery and then bootstrap.js. I got these errors when trying the other way around: Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
bootstrap3-jquery.html:57 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.11.2... when I change it to 2.2.4 as you've used, the modal window doesn't appear at all on window load.  I have jQuery loading first, and that gets the modal to appear (still no backdrop), but if I load bootstrap.js first, then the modal doesn't appear.

Comment: script structure is like this after body tag. My code works now. need to clean the browser cached memory . :)  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<script Src= "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" >
</script>

<script src="custom.js"></script>

</html>

Comment: Mine still won't work with anything other than jquery 1.11.2. :(

Comment: use jquery 2.1.3 if you are using bootstrap 3.3.2

Comment: Ok, finally working. I'm marking this as the correct answer, but the final obstacle was that I needed to add "bottom:0;" to the modal-backdrop class in my CSS. I read this somewhere else on SO; Not sure if that was originally in my CSS and I deleted it by accident? But once I added it there, everything works. Thanks for your help too, @MostafaBaezid! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a div tag with modal-backdrop fade in class after closing the div tag for modal to attain the backdrop look.

Also ensure you remove it with jquery on closing the modal.

```
Example:

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal show" role="dialog">
</div> <!-- end of modal -->

<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
```

Codepen link:

http://codepen.io/saa93/pen/amNpyg

Comment: Your Codepen doesn't show that additional <div> tag with class="modal-backdrop fade"... so it's not working as you described.